# Link to a document In another document library in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Link to a document In another document library.
The “Link to a Document” content type does not exist in as an option in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does

You can check it at
`/_layouts/15/ManageContentType.aspx?ctype=0x01010A`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add the Link to Document content type to the library.

First go to advanced settings for the library and enable management of content types, then in the library settings under content types click to add an existing content type. Pick the Link to Document content type.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on "**Allow Management of Content Types**" in the **Advanced settings** of the library settings